# How to use radio group in shared preference?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, radio-group

I'm doing my mobile project, I'm using shared preference to save user's clicks for later usage. One of them is radio buttons, after some research I found that to get the specific radio button that was clicked, I have to use radio Group. When I tried that, it only enables me to click on one radio button the other one when I click o it, the app is forced to stop. I have created a class called Preference.java to set and get all of user clicks, including radio buttons.

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private Preferences preferences;
    final String KEY_SAVED_CAR_INDEX = "KEY_SAVED_CAR_INDEX";
    final String KEY_SAVED_MAN_INDEX = "KEY_SAVED_MAN_INDEX";
    Button clickbtn;
    CheckBox start_from_home;
    RadioButton carchecked, manchecked;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    Spinner spinner ;
    EditText ed1;
    int selectedPosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);

        spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_hours);
        selectedPosition= spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

        clickbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click_btn);
        clickbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                init();
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }

        });

        start_from_home =(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.start_check);
        start_from_home.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(start_from_home.isChecked()) {
                    preferences = new Preferences(MainActivity.this);
                    preferences.setstartfromhome(b);
                }
            }
        });

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
//        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(radioGroupOnCheckedChangeListener);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int checkedId) {
                RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewById(checkedId);
                int checkedIndex = radioGroup.indexOfChild(checkedRadioButton);
                int radioButtonID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                preferences = new Preferences(MainActivity.this);

                if(radioButtonID == R.id.car_radio) {
                    preferences.settransportationchecked(KEY_SAVED_CAR_INDEX, checkedIndex);
                }
                else if (radioButtonID== R.id.man_radio)
                    preferences.settransportationchecked(KEY_SAVED_MAN_INDEX,checkedIndex);
}
        });

    }
private void init() {

        preferences = new Preferences(MainActivity.this);

        preferences.setcurrentlocation(ed1.getText().toString());
     preferences.setspinnerhours(selectedPosition);
    }


}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edittext1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/car_radio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/click_btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="Car" />



        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/man_radio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Walking"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_below="@+id/car_radio"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="51dp" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Preference.java

```
public void settransportationchecked(String key, int value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("preferences", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Please post the logs

Comment: What is reason to do onclick listener for radio button man_radio in layout file. What it does?  Pls post the entire activity to understand the issue

Comment: i'm  sorry could you please specify more what do you mean bu 'logs'? thank you

Comment: to answer you second question, i just wanted to save what type of transportation does he want walking"which is the man" or by car for later usage in the project. @lib4

Comment: Adb logcat the reason for crash might be printed in the android studio logcat session

Comment: onRadioButtonClicked did u implemented this in your code,  if yes pls post the code. Or post the enire activity class

Comment: i'm sorry i'm kinda new in android, thus i haven't heard of logcat before. is there another way to answer you question if i could not reach adb logcat?

Comment: Possible to post entire activity class?

Comment: to answer the question did i implement the onRadioButtonCLicked, no i haven't after researching in the radio group, neither of the examples that i saw on the internet implemented it

Comment: right now i'm changing the activity class code

Comment: android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked pls remove it from layout file and try.

Comment: okay i will do it right now, i have updated the full code of MainActivity.java

Comment: it worked as you said it seems to be that the reason it didn't work was the onclick was different from what was actually implemented. now i have to find out if it is actually saving in the shared preference

Comment: Could you please up vote my comments

Comment: it saved the value!! thank you @lib4

Comment: right away, thank you

Comment: Please accept my answer. To help the others. Thank you.

Comment: done thank you @lib4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked
```

pls remove it from layout file and try and it seems that its not implemented.